# Javascript order on Ruby on Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am adding a slider and news ticker to a view page in my Ruby on Rails 3 application.

```
<%= render 'layouts/main_slider' %>
<%= render 'layouts/news_slider' %>
```

These pages have the following scripts and the errors I recieve are:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ticker'
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'defaults' of undefined
```

For this script:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

<script> 
$(function () {
$('#js-news').ticker();
});
</script>

<script>
$.fn.ticker.defaults = {
    speed: 0.10,            
    ajaxFeed: false,
    feedUrl: '',
    feedType: 'xml',
    displayType: 'fade',
    htmlFeed: true,
    debugMode: true,
    controls: true,
    titleText: 'Latest',    
    direction: 'ltr',   
    pauseOnItems: 3000,
    fadeInSpeed: 600,
    fadeOutSpeed: 300
};  
</script>
```

I also get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'
```

For this script:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#mainslider').nivoSlider({
          effect:'fade',
          pauseTime:8000,
          animSpeed: 500
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bxslider
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.ticker.js
//= require jquery.nivo.slider.js
//= require jquery-1.10.2.min.js
//= require bootstrap.min.js
//= require jquery-tablesorter
//= require_tree .
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'paperclip', "~> 3.0"
gem "rest-client", "~> 1.6.7"
gem 'jquery-tablesorter'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'bxslider-rails'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
 gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :development do
gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end
```

I did a bundle install and a rake assets:clean && rake assets:precompile
Is the order wrong in my .js file? Am I missing a gem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're having issues with the order of your includes.
You need to include jQuery before anything that depends on it, and not load it again after (or the changes any plugins made will typically disappear).

If `//= require jquery` loads jQuery (which is probably the case, else all your plugins would be throwing errors about an undefined `jQuery` or `$`), then you should probably get rid of the line that says `//= require jquery-1.10.2.min.js`.  Actually, you should probably get rid of the file as well (unless `jquery.js` is just a symlink to it), lest `//= require_tree .` include it anyway.

Comment: I removed //= require jquery-1.10.2.min.js as you informed me and all errors are gone. It was overwriting, thanks!